# Swift unable to sort Dictionary by Value [String: Int]

Tags: swift

I created a Dictionary with the Userid and the timestamp from my Database. Unfortunately, the results which I store in a new dictionary are always in the same order. If I print the key and value out, and there it's right.

Here is my Code:

```
 func sortUsers(){
    let sorted = someProtocol.sorted {$0.value > $1.value}  // or {$0.value < $1.value} to sort using the dictionary values
    sortedValues.removeAll()

    for (idx,element) in sorted.enumerated(){
        let value = element.value
        let key  = element.key
        self.sortedValues[key] = value
        print("sorted Key and Value", sorted.key, sorted.value
        if idx == sorted.endIndex-1{
            self.downloadUserProfile(sortedValues: sortedValues)
            print("sorted", sortedValues)
        }
    }
}
```

Output of first print:

> sorted key and value vhsIe0nBBWQ0D9csBpLwgL4Mf293 9999999
>   sorted key and value ZYpiuLBRJkcM1cK6tDctKYva7UB3 9999998

output of dict:

> sorted ["ZYpiuLBRJkcM1cK6tDctKYva7UB3": 9999998, "vhsIe0nBBWQ0D9csBpLwgL4Mf293": 9999999]

Comment: I don’t quite understand your question.  Can you please edit your question to show what the expected output is?

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. `sortedValues` will never be sorted.

Comment: @rmaddy and what should i use instead

Comment: When order is important you use an array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array of tuples instead of a dictionary

```
var arr = [("CCC", 333), ("DDD",444), ("AAA",222), ("BBB", 111)]
arr.sort { return $0.1 < $1.1 }
```